# Count number of surveys that had 2 specific questions both answered Yes

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to count how many surveys came back but only if both question 7 and 9 were answered yes.  I can get the count of 1 or the other but not if both questions are Yes in the same survey (this is as far as I got):

```
SELECT
count(if(question.id = '7' and value = 'Yes',1,null)) as A
count(if(question.id = '9' and value = 'Yes',1,null)) as B
FROM questions
```

Survey(id)

| Question (Question.id) | Answer (value=Yes/No/Null) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | No |
| 2 | Yes |
| 3 |  |
| 4 | No |
| 5 | Yes |
| 6 | No |
| 7 | Yes |
| 8 |  |
| 9 | Yes |

Comment: What `RDBM` you are using? Also, it will be great if you post a sample of your table.

Comment: Yep! Using TQL and added a sample of the table to the original post.

Comment: I see no survey related column[s] in the table.

Answer (score 0):

How about just simply the solution by getting count of all the valid scenarios for question ID 7 and 9 And then Grouping based on Survey ID.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM questions 
WHERE questions.id IN (7,9) AND questions.value IN ('Yes')
GROUP BY SurveyID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that the following query helps you:

```
Select Count(D.surveyId) CNT From
(
  Select  surveyId,Count(*) cn
  From questions
  Where (qid=7 Or qid=9) And (answer='yes')
  Group By surveyId
  Having Count(*)=2
) D
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7a671410f28bc3535a7ba833efe52ed7).

Comment: Thanks! You went a step further getting the count of the surveys which was the next part I was stuck on so it saved me an extra question :)